# exception translation with jpa template spring

Tags: spring, jpa, exception

I have my application in Spring / JPA. Spring translate database exception into Runtime exception called DataAccessException. I have unique constraint on one of my column and I want to display user defined message that Value for this column already exists. But when I retrieve message using `e.getMessage();` it just give me Could not execute JDBC batch update. Which is insufficient. 
Can I get any database specific error code the way database vendor returns so that I can do some mappping based on that.

spring does provide sql-error-code.xml using which we can translate. But I am using jpatemplate and not jdbcTemplate. 
Please help me as I am new to exception handling in spring.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the spring manual:

> Spring provides a convenient translation from technology-specific exceptions like SQLException to its own exception class hierarchy with the DataAccessException as the root exception. These exceptions wrap the original exception so there is never any risk that one might lose any information as to what might have gone wrong.

You should catch the Spring DataIntegrityViolationException and then set whatever use message makes sense for your user.

Full list of exceptions here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html

Comment: I tried catching DataIntegrityViolationException. But I am not getting proper message. It just gives me message like "Can not execute JDBC Batch update." I can not figure out what is wrong from this message. Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: Are you trynig to help the user or typing to figure out for yourself what is wrong. If you are trying to figure it out for yourself configure hibernate to print out the SQL that is is sending to the db to see what column is affected. The message that is stored in the exception will depend on the type of jdbc driver being used some will give detailed messages others more cryptic ones.